# duda con bootbox alert (jquery) y el llenado de su configuración

Tags: jquery

Estoy utilizando Bootbox alert en su modalidad "Prompt with select"

http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html#prompt-with-select

Según su documentación hay que llenarlo con estos parámetros.

```
bootbox.prompt({
    title: "This is a prompt with select!",
    inputType: 'select',
    inputOptions: [
        {
            text: 'Choose one...',
            value: '',
        },
        {
            text: 'Choice One',
            value: '1',
        },
        {
            text: 'Choice Two',
            value: '2',
        },
        {
            text: 'Choice Three',
            value: '3',
        }
    ],
    callback: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

yo ya tengo un array previamente generado con la info de "text" y "value".
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como hago para generar código "al vuelo" (en vivo, en ejecución), para que llene el "inputOptions" con la información de mi array previamente generado?

o más en concreto ¿Como lleno la configuración "inputOptions" de bootbox si la info que me genera el array es totalmente dinámica?

Este es mi código:

```
$( "#movervarioscorreos" ).click(function() {
    carpetas = [];
    $("#carpetas .carpeta").each(function(){
        carpetas.push({"carpeta":$(this).attr("name"),"path":$(this).attr("id")});
    });

    console.log(carpetas);


if(movidos==''){
    bootbox.alert({
        message: "No ha seleccionado ningún objeto.",
        className: 'bb-alternate-modal'
    });
}else{
        bootbox.prompt({
        title: "¿Realmente desea eliminar los objetos seleccionados? <br> No será posible recuperarlos nuevamente.",
        inputType: 'select',
       inputOptions: [
            {
                text: 'Carpeta1',
                value: 'path1',
            },
            {
                text: 'Carpeta2',
                value: 'path2',
            },
            {
                text: 'Carpeta2',
                value: 'path3',
            },
            {
                text: 'Carpeta4',
                value: 'path4',
            }
        ],
        callback: function (result) {
            if (result){
                $.ajax({
                    url:"../../views/ajax.php",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:datos,
                    cache:false,
                    contentType:false,
                    processData:false,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $('#loader').removeClass('hidden');
                    },
                    success: function(regreso){
                        alert(regreso);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
});
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo tienes que cambiar el nombre de las propieadas e igualar el inputOptions al array que has generado.  Algo asi:

```
$( "#movervarioscorreos" ).click(function() {
    carpetas = [];
    $("#carpetas .carpeta").each(function(){
        carpetas.push({"text":$(this).attr("name"),"value":$(this).attr("id")});
    });

    console.log(carpetas);    

    if(movidos==''){
      bootbox.alert({
        message: "No ha seleccionado ningún objeto.",
        className: 'bb-alternate-modal'
      });
    }else{
      bootbox.prompt({
        title: "¿Realmente desea eliminar los objetos seleccionados? <br> No será posible recuperarlos nuevamente.",
        inputType: 'select',
        inputOptions: carpetas,
        callback: function (result) {
            if (result){
                $.ajax({
                    url:"../../views/ajax.php",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:datos,
                    cache:false,
                    contentType:false,
                    processData:false,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $('#loader').removeClass('hidden');
                    },
                    success: function(regreso){
                        alert(regreso);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: Es verdad tienes razón, al final el inputOptions es un array. :/ muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ya a estos niveles mi mente pasó desapercibido ese gran detalle. Muy amable, gracias.